# How can I print the SQL query executed after Perl's DBI fills in the placeholders?

Tags: mysql, sql, perl, prepared-statement, dbi

I'm using Perl's DBI module. I prepare a statement using placeholders, then execute the query.

Is it possible to print out the final query that was executed without manually escaping the parameters and dropping them into the placeholders?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make DBI log all queries including params?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703521/how-can-i-make-dbi-log-all-queries-including-params)

Comment: @Jake this question was asked 4 years before the other question, also this question has better answers, (in my opinion). That's why I've marked the other question as the duplicate and candidate for closure.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See [Tracing in DBI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBI#TRACING). The following works using `DBD::SQLite` but produces a lot of output:

```
$dbh->trace($dbh->parse_trace_flags('SQL|1|test'));
```

Output:

`<- prepare('SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... = ?')= DBI::st=HASH(0x21ee924) at booklet-excel.pl line 213`

`<- execute('Inhaler')= '0E0' at booklet-excel.pl line 215`

etc etc.

You could [plug your own filter in to the trace stream](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBI#Tracing-to-Layered-Filehandles) to only keep `prepare`s.

Comment: Upvoted for teaching me about trace, even though it doesn't answer the question (because as others pointed out, it's impossible). And this comment is here just because I feel guilty for upvoting an answer that I know doesn't answer the question. lol :$

Answer (score 11):

You can do a debug print of a prepared statement using the [Statement](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.636/DBI.pm#Statement) attribute. This can be accessed either with a "statement handle" or a "database handle".

```
print $sth->{Statement} # with a statement handle

print $dbh->{Statement} # with a database handle
```

Comment: This simply returns the string passed to the last `prepare` or `do`, so placeholders aren't filled in as the OP requested.

Comment: Could use `print Dumper( $statement_handle->{'ParamValues'} );`
to print the bind params separately - Might be enough to debug the majority of queries.

Answer (score 10):

Not in general, because DBI doesn't necessarily produce such a query.  If your database supports prepared statements and placeholders in its API, DBI will pass them through and let the database do the work, which is one of the reasons to use prepared statements.

Answer (score 5):

This works for `DBD::mysql` with server-side prepare disabled (the default):

```
$ DBI_TRACE=2 perl your-script-here
```

It will print each statement twice, once before binding parameters and once after. The latter will be well-formed SQL that you can run yourself.

There is also a module, [DBI::Log](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI::Log), which only prints SQL statements (no other debug noise), and optional timing information and caller stacktraces. It's really useful.

Comment: Best answer here!

Answer (score 1):

As masto says in general the placeholders in the SQL are not directly replaced with your parameters. The whole point of parameterized SQL is the SQL with placeholders is passed to the database engine to parse once and then it just receives the parameters.

As idssl notes you can obtain the SQL back from the statement or connection handle and you can also retrieve the parameters from [ParamValues](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.622/DBI.pm#ParamValues). If you don't want to do this yourself you can use something like [DBIx::Log4perl](http://search.cpan.org/~mjevans/DBIx-Log4perl-0.24/lib/DBIx/Log4perl.pm) to log just the SQL and parameters. See DBIX_L4P_LOG_DELAYBINDPARAM which outputs something like this:

```
DEBUG - prepare(0.1): 'insert into mje values(?,?)'
DEBUG - $execute(0.1) = [{':p1' => 1,':p2' => 'fred'},undef];
```

Of course as it uses Log::Log4perl you can omit the "DEBUG - " if you want. There is a small tutorial for using DBIx::Log4perl [here](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/perl/dbi-debugging.html#log4perl).

You should be able to use DBIx::Log4perl with any DBD and if you cannot for some reason RT it and I will look at it.

If you don't want to go with DBIx::Log4perl and the DBI trace options don't suit your needs you can write callbacks for DBI's prepare/select*/execute methods and gather whatever you like in them.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to create your own tracer module (as suggested by Sinan), you are better off just trying to print the argument hash before it is passed to `$sth->execute()`. This is especially true, since the "Trace" functionality is DBMS dependent and `$sth->{Statement}` only returns the SQL placeholder statement. Here's what I did.

```
...
while (my $row = $csv->getline_hr($fh)) {
    my $cval = "";
    my $tquery = $query;
    foreach my $j (@cols) { 
            $cval = $row->{$j};
            $tquery =~ s/\?/\'$cval\'/;
    }
    print "$tquery\n\n";
    $rc = $sth->execute(@{$row}{@cols});
}
```

Where I have used Text::CSV... 
**NOTE**: This is not exact, due to DBMS implementation dependent handling of {'}s.

Answer (score 1):

For the majority of queries, the simplest debugging is to use the following...

- If you prepare and execute a single statement using `do` method, use:

  ```
   use feature 'say';
   say $dbh->{Statement};
  ```
- If you use `prepare` and `execute` methods separately, use:

  ```
   use feature 'say';
   use Data::Dumper;
   $Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;
   say $sth->{Statement};
   say Dumper($sth->{ParamValues});
  ```

Answer (score 0):

For perl neophytes, my solution, copied from not2qubit and simplified/hopefully made a bit more generic/reuseable:

```
sub dump_query {
  my $tquery = shift;
  my @args = shift;
  my $j;
    foreach my $j (@args) { $tquery =~ s/\?/\'$j\'/; }
    print STDERR "$tquery\n\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put:

```
$dbh->trace(2);
```

before the prepare and execute statements. This will output lots of debugging information, including the sql with the binding values.

Just be cautious when using this in a production environment, as query tracing can reveal sensitive information and should be used for debugging or development purposes only.